# How to prevent API request source spoofing?

Tags: api, rest, security, oauth

**Background**

I'm writing my own API with OAUTH etcetera.

And I'd like users to be able to get x free requests and after that they have to pay a small price, because servers aren't free. Is there a way to prevent bad people from stealing the tokens (inside for example an android application's code) and generating their own requests, exhausting 
 the requests from my original users?
An important part of the question is: Can I secure that the request is made from a certain platform: Is it made from an android phone for example.
Because there will be different prices per platform.

**My own thoughts**

- Headers can be faked, that will only create a false sense of security
- Is there for the most popular type of platforms (iOS, android, WP,
  CMSes, desktop apps) a safe way to store credentials while
  developing? (do I miss some platforms that people would like to use and aren't safe?)
- If so, can I write libraries that force the developer to store his tokens in that safe way instead of hardcoding them?
- Ip based doesn't work for mobile applications, although
  you could limit the requests accepted per IP

if the answer is no:

**Possible consequences**

what is currently preventing me from

1. downloading an app that is using the google maps api and 
   decompiling it.
2. extract the tokens
3. generating a lot of request just to mess with the developers (curl)

People will get a licence for wordpress, but by spoofing will also use their credentials for a mobile app.

*disclaimer: I don't have malicious intentions, but I try to understand how to prevent people who have*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer is *no*. You need to distribute your tokens widely into environments you have zero control over, so you've automatically lost. There is no universally "secure" way to store anything which you could force everyone to use (wouldn't it be great if there was though?).

In order to track usage, you need to authenticate users, which you do with tokens, and which you need to expect to be stolen/leaked/misused. That's typically why you have tokens in the first place instead of passwords: because you can revoke and regenerate tokens. Who is hurt most if a token gets misused? The developer this token belongs to. So they have a great incentive to store those tokens as securely as possible; leave it up to them to figure out the best way. What you can do is to proactively inform developers if their tokens display unusual behaviour, and make it easy for them to revoke and regenerate tokens themselves.

Comment: I agree with most part of what you say: but I added an example in which not the developer but me is hurt the most. If I have different api usage licenses and he abuses licence 1 to get licence 2 for free (use it for another platform as what he paid for). Still +1 one for the rest of the smart solution.

Comment: That, quite honestly, is a business model that IMO simply can't fly. You charge differently based on the *type of client* which is making requests, even if the requests themselves are basically indistinguishable, and when it's technically impossible to identify the type of client making the requests.

Comment: Well that was exactly the question. The business model is based on the same concept that Windows has a pro and a home version: you use more ways to use my API, you pay more. You don't know what I serve so I understand the idea is really abstract. But the reason is that to create compatible modules for the CMSes and libraries for the mobile platforms costs money to develop and that way I can manage the development cost by demand. (maybe I'm silly)

Comment: Windows physically contains or lacks actual code *and* they control the entire license enforcement stack top to bottom. You on the other hand just have HTTP requests to work with, where the client runs open source code (for the most part). Your only hope there would be some pre-compiled extension, stuff like ZendGuard, and even that's not anywhere near unhackable. Legal protections are your best bet here, not technical measures.

Comment: great answer, as for the microsoft part: yes I know, I just wanted to tell you where I got the idea. It's actually really obvious now that it's hard to check which "client" is used. I'm still wondering how Google checks their android api isn't used in a windows desktop app, any guesses?

Comment: Since they quite frequently update their apps, my best guess would be that they're simply rotating their tokens often, simply counting on the fact that any illicit use automatically eventually expires and it's too much trouble for such users to keep up with that. The good ol' cat and mouse game. You can also count on such misuse to always stay pretty minimal and on the down low, since nobody will write a blog post about how to abuse Google's APIs, since Google would know about that within minutes and can shut it down.

Comment: that answer made me chuckle